# Trigonometry equation maximum

Tags: trigonometry

Given the equation: $\cos x + \sqrt3 \sin x = a^2$  find the maximum value for $a$ for which the equation has solutions and for this case solve the equation, $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm guessing I need to find the maximum for the function and for this I have to differentiate it and solve it when it's derivative is $0$? At a first glance I'd say the maximum for $a$ is $\sqrt2$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$, but how do I go around proving this?

Comment: I think you already explained how to go about it..so get to it ;)! and remember $a(x)$. so we need $a'(x) = 0$

Comment: Suppose you were asked to work on $A\sin p \cos x  + A \cos p \sin x $. Can you think of a way to simplify that? ($A$ and $p$ are constants). Hint: that's actually the situation you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos x+\sqrt 3\sin x=2\left( \frac 12\cos x+\frac {\sqrt 3}2\sin x \right)$$
$$=2\left( \sin\frac{\pi}6\cos x+\cos\frac{\pi}6\sin x \right)$$
$$=2\sin\left( x+\frac{\pi}6 \right)=a^2$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yup, it was easy to finish from here. But I have to ask, how did you see that this equation can be simplified to a sin(a+b) sort of thing? I would've never figured that out. Is practice and experience the only way to see those things?

Comment: I have seen problems like that before at this site, so it was intuitive to me. However, this technique can be done for any $$A\cos cx+B\sin cx=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos cx+\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin cx\right)$$ where those coefficients are sine and cosine of $\theta=\operatorname{atan2}(A,B)$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) for more about the atan2 function: it is quite useful. This technique works if the multiplier of $x$ inside the sine and cosine are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since \begin{align}\cos x+\sqrt 3\sin x &=2\left( \frac 12\cos x+\frac {\sqrt 3}2\sin x \right) \\
& =2 \sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{6}\right) = a^2\end{align}

Since $\sin x$ oscillates between $-1$ and $1$, we need $\displaystyle -1 \leq \frac{a^2}{2} \leq 1$. The maximum value of $a$ is easily seen to be $a = \sqrt{2}$ since $\displaystyle \frac{a^2}{2}\leq 1 \implies a^2 \leq 2$.

---

An alternative way (but much less elegant, imo) is to differentiate and set the derivative equal to zero, as shown below:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\cos x + \sqrt{3} \sin x\right) = \sqrt{3}\cos x - \sin x.$$

The derivative first vanishes at $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and has the general solution of $x = n\pi - \frac{2\pi}{3}$. When $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$, you need only check that this is a maximum point (hint: look at the second derivative) then substitute it into the original equation to deduce that $a^2 = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
and with no originality:

If
$f(x)
=a \sin x + b \cos x
$,
let
$c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
Then
$f(x)
=c(\frac{a}{c} \sin x + \frac{b}{c} \cos x)
=c(A \sin x + B \cos x)
$.

Since
$A^2+B^2 = 1$,
there is an angle 
$\theta$
such that
$\cos \theta = A$
and
$\sin \theta = B$.

Therefore
$f(x)
=c(\cos \theta \sin x + \sin \theta \cos x)
=c \sin(x+ \theta)
$.

Therefore,
$|f(x)|
\le c
$
and this value is attained
for $x = -\theta$.

In this case,
$a = 1$
and $b = \sqrt{3}$,
so the max is
$\sqrt{1+3}
= 2
$.